# EJS view not updating after boolean change

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

So I have a login box and a registration box.
I'm trying to update the view if register is clicked. the boolean is changing in the console but the view is not

index.ejs

```
    <%- include('partials/header') -%>

<% if (locals.isAuthenticated) { %>
    <p>You are logged in. <a href="/profile" class="underline">View your profile</a>.</p>
<% } else if (!this.isRegister) { %>
    <%- include('partials/loginbox') -%>
<% } else { %>
    <%- include('partials/registerbox') -%>
<% } %>

<%- include('partials/footer') -%>
```

script in body in footer.ejs:

```
<script>

    var isRegister = false;

function register() {
    this.isRegister = !this.isRegister;
    console.log(this.isRegister);
    return this.isRegister
};

</script>
```

button in loginbox.ejs:

```
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="register()">Register</button>
```

Comment: The EJS program is executed (presumably) on  your HTTP server. The `<script>` program is executed in the browser. They are different programs and do not share variables. Even if they did, the change to the variable when the button is clicked would not travel back through time to the point where the `if` statement was executed in the EJS program. Submit a form to the server and process the change in data server side.

Comment: Thank you, coming from Angular so a quick conditional in the html works there.

Comment: @Quentin, How would I go about getting the update to work? I'm not familiar with EJS

Comment: Submit a form to the server. Send the new HTML back.